# Static HTML site within Sharepoint

Tags: html, 2003

We have a need to drop a static HTML page/collection of pages and associated assets (javascript, css, images, swfs etc) into a Sharepoint site and ideally make them the root of the site. I.e. when you visit the site you go directly to the index.html.

This page/site would then link out to other pages within the sharepoint site.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why does it have to be a static page? Why can't you add whatever you need to SharePoints normal home page?

Answer (score 1):

This should still be possible using FrontPage instead of SharePoint Designer.

In the Folder List, right-click the page that you want as your new home page, and then click 'Set as Home Page'.
 NOTE   If the Folder List is hidden, on the View menu, click Folder List.

Instructions taken from the link below:

[Navigation in Frontpage 2003.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/frontpage-help/create-a-navigation-structure-HP001039383.aspx)

[Please see these instructions for how Frontpage 2003 can be used with SharePoint 2003.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc767097.aspx)

[Here is a free, quick course offered by Microsoft on how to use FrontPage 2003.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/frontpage-help/create-a-web-site-with-frontpage-RZ006179028.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharePoint designer to upload html file to the root of the site and then go to site settings page and set the welcome page.

If you want to automate it, you should be able to provision html at the root of the site by a FEATURE that uses Module element.

From VS.NET add project item of type Module, replace sample.txt with your html file and make sure the elements.xml looks like below assuming you have sample.htm file abd your module name is RootModule. The name of module and html file can be different in your case.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="RootModule">
  <File Path="RootModule\Sample.html" Url="Sample.html" />
</Module>
</Elements>
```

Sometimes the html files doe not render and it asks to download it, if so, check [How do I prevent Sharepoint from asking to download html files to my local machine?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39020/how-do-i-prevent-sharepoint-from-asking-to-download-html-files-to-my-local-machi)

Comment: Hi Ashish, could you confirm whether this feature has specific Sharepoint version requirements?

Comment: no, this should work in WSS 3.0/ SharePoint Foundation and MOSS 2007/ SP 2010

Comment: It looks like we may be limited to 2003/WSS2.0. Do you know if that would still be possible?

Comment: Do you know if it's possible with 2003, or would you be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Sorry, I have never worked on 2003. I cannot comment on that.