# How do I stop Sharepoint 2010 from asking to download html links as files?

Tags: 2010, javascript, html

At first glance it looked as though my issue was one that could be resolved by implementing the fix mentioned [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/39021/14477) but I am still encountering the issue being that html links are being downloaded rather than opened. The html pages themselves contain a fair amount of Javascript, would this cause this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the web app has it's file handling set to permissive, it can be overriden at the library level.

It can be set via powershell like this:

```
$site = Get-SPSite("http://sbx01/sites/Harry")
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
$list = $web.GetList("http://sbx01/sites/Harry/Shared Documents")   
$list.browserfilehandling                      // list the current value  

$list.browserfilehandling = "Permissive" 
$list.update()
$list.browserfilehandling                      // list the value again
```

It can be set in other ways as per this reference:

http://sharepointconnoisseur.blogspot.com.au/2011/11/tips-to-resolve-sharepoint-2010-users.html