# SharePoint Foundation 2013 HTML file issue related to Articulate Storyline

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, html, sharepoint-hosted-app

I use Articulate Storyline to develop eLearning and I publish the project to SharePoint.  A published Articulate Storyline project includes hundreds of files; traditionally, the key was to post a link to the story.html file, and that ran the eLearning seamlessly.  Note that those taking the eLearning do not have Articulate licenses; they access the training on SharePoint.

This method worked fine until my organization recently migrated from SharePoint Foundation 2010 to SharePoint Foundation 2013.  Now SharePoint asks me if I want to Save the file.  Saving the file won't work.  The file is merely a directory that pulls the necessary graphics, video, etc., files as needed.

My SharePoint admin is unfamiliar with Articulate and does not quite understand why or how the story.html file runs the eLearning.

I saw this answer [How do I prevent Sharepoint from asking to download html files to my local machine?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39020/how-do-i-prevent-sharepoint-from-asking-to-download-html-files-to-my-local-machi) and suspect my issue is security-related.

HELP!

Comment: The solution is likely to be in the question you link to, precisely this: `Add-SPAllowedInlineDownloadedMimeType -WebApplication http://mywebapp -MimeType "text/html"`

Comment: In case anyone else encounters this, the solution was to link to the .swf file instead of the .html file.

Answer (score 0):

How do I prevent SharePoint from asking to download html files to my local machine for storyline?

You can easily display your Storyline content if you're using SharePoint Online. Perform these steps in order to display the content:

If you haven't already done so, publish your Storyline content to Web.

1. Go to your document storage.
2. Create a folder for your course. Essentially, you're recreating the folder hierarchy exported from your story content, and the hierarchy should match exactly.
3. Open the folder you created.
4. Upload those few files into that folder.
5. Create a new folder entitled `story_content`. You can only upload 100 files at a time, so it's good to jot down the last file you uploaded to reference in the next batch.
6. Open `story_content` and upload all those files.
7. Create a slides folder and upload those files into it.
8. Go back to your main folder.

Next Steps:

SharePoint Online automatically downloads .html files; therefore, you need to change the story.html file to story.aspx in order to play your content.

1. Open the story.html file in a simple content editor, such as Notepad or Adobe Dreamweaver.
2. Save the files as story.aspx.

Final Steps:

1. Upload story.aspx to your SharePoint course folder.
2. Test your work by clicking on the story.aspx file. It should launch the course seamlessly.

Check out this simple screencast I created (attached) that demonstrates the process.