# HTML page stored in SharePoint document library is not opening

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, html

I have stored HTML page in a SharePoint document library but whenever I click on that HTML page , it is showing white page .

Comment: I think you should use Page library instead of Document Library

Comment: Nope cant move the file from Document Library . Its actually a saved HTML page .

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the page to an .aspx instead of a .html - if I remember correctly there's a security measure preventing using .html files in the newer versions of SharePoint.

Edit:
If it's not an option to change the file type you can change the setting. For further information please see this post (I can't take credit for anything other than finding it): [How do I prevent Sharepoint from asking to download html files to my local machine?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39020/how-do-i-prevent-sharepoint-from-asking-to-download-html-files-to-my-local-machi)

Comment: i tried that but still not working .

Comment: Then I would check out the link to change the security level.